# Migrating from AK4 to AK5 - AKOscillatorBank change to Synth

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm migrating my project from AudioKit 4 to AudioKit 5 and currently stuck on a bad access error. The variables look like they are passed correctly into the SynthVoiceStart method. I'm quite stumped why it's throwing the error as it should be a simple change from AKOScillatorBank to the Synth object.

The project code is accessible [HERE](https://github.com/Oli-C/SynthSquares) on GitHub.

I've attached a screenshot below.

[XCode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz0v3.jpg)

Comment: Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

In the past I've investigated and managed to solve EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors with AudioKit by using Address Sanitizer (ASan). In XCode go to `Edit Scheme`, `Diagnostics` tab, and tick the `Address Sanitizer` option. When your program is recompiled and run, ASan will print a report whenever a memory error occurs. This sometimes gives useful information to resolve the error.

[image: Edit Scheme with the Address Sanitizer option shown]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, a simple mistake on my part.

```
let engine = AudioEngine()
```

Was accidentally inside the 'init' method and was not declared beforehand. This meant that AudioKit did not start correctly.

The corrected code is below.

[XCode Correct Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKopD.png)